# How to have cursor change with buttonclick

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, mouse-cursor

I have set up a switcher on my website to toggle between normal mouse / pointer & a Lego hand as a cursor and a head as pointer. However, I can only get the cursor to show when clicking the switcher. How can I also add this pointer

(`cursor: url(https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0571/7137/8349/files/pointer.png?v=1644096049), pointer;`)

It should be assigned to the following classes:

a, button, input, input, button, a, input, .slider, .round

I have then also added a snippet, which lets the switcher / checkbox stay on checked...
(You can see that on this video [password is 12345678]: https://easyupload.io/gknxoi)

However after a reload of the page for example, the switcher stays on checked, but the cursor doesn't show up...

```js
var cbs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');
for (var i = 0; i < cbs.length; i++) {
  cbs[i].addEventListener('change', function() {
    if (this.checked) {
      document.body.style.cursor = "url(https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0571/7137/8349/files/cursor.png?v=1644096068), auto";
    } else {
      document.body.style.cursor = "default";
    }
  });
}


$(function() {
  var test = localStorage.input === 'true' ? true : false;
  $('input').prop('checked', test || false);
});

$('input').on('change', function() {
  localStorage.input = $(this).is(':checked');
  console.log($(this).is(':checked'));
});
```

```css
.switcheronheader {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 17px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}

.mouseswitcher {
  /*   border-left: 1px solid #248751; */
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.switcheronheader input {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 13px;
  width: 13px;
  left: 2px;
  bottom: 2px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked+.slider {
  background-color: #248751;
}

input:focus+.slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked+.slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(13px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(13px);
  transform: translateX(13px);
}

.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mouseswitcher">

  <label class="switcheronheader">
                     <input type="checkbox" id="overheaderswitch">
                     <span class="slider round"></span>
                </label>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```css
a, input, button, .slider, .round {
  margin: 15px;
  cursor:url(https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0571/7137/8349/files/pointer.png?v=1644096049), auto;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="lego"/>
<a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">link to google.com</a>
```

Comment: I have tried this one before, but I want the cursor to change on the button change... So there is some javascript needed! But thanks for your answer :)

Comment: If you know JavaScript well, we would also need to put this into the javscript, so the lego head (cursor) only shows when switch is on active...

Answer (score 0):

Use `document.querySelector('html')` instead of `document.body` will make it work.

Also, use `cursor: auto` instead of `cursor: default`

```js
var cbs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');
for (var i = 0; i < cbs.length; i++) {
  cbs[i].addEventListener('change', function() {
    if (this.checked) {
      document.querySelector('html').style.cursor= ' url(https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0571/7137/8349/files/cursor.png?v=1644096068), auto'
      document.querySelector('label').style.cursor = ' url(https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0571/7137/8349/files/cursor.png?v=1644096068), auto'
    } else {
       document.querySelector('html').style.cursor = "auto";
      document.querySelector('label').style.cursor = 'auto'
    }
    
  });
}
```

```css
.switcheronheader {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 17px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}

.mouseswitcher {
  /*   border-left: 1px solid #248751; */
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.switcheronheader input {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 13px;
  width: 13px;
  left: 2px;
  bottom: 2px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked+.slider {
  background-color: #248751;
}

input:focus+.slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked+.slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(13px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(13px);
  transform: translateX(13px);
}

.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mouseswitcher">

  <label class="switcheronheader">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="overheaderswitch">
                     <span class="slider round"></span>
                </label>

</div>
```

Comment: Okay, thanks so much, I will try this out right now!

Comment: Okay, I have just tried It out, it basically has the same function as before, only the mouse cursor changes, and on reload the button stays on activated, but the cursor doesn't show.... How  can we also change the pointer on checking the switch?

Comment: @raffaelbaer, my problem, doesn't pay attention to the problem, update the code just now. it should works by adding style to `label` to override its default cursor style